# openapi, list of strings as query parameter

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm defining a query parameter, with openapi 3.0.1, as follows

```
{
  "name" : "sort",
  "in" : "query",
  "description" : "Sorting criteria. Example: productCode,desc",
  "required" : false,
  "explode" : false,
  "schema" : {
    "type" : "array",
    "items" : {
      "type" : "string"
    }
  }
}
```

On swagger-ui 3.51.1 if I add two strings

```
"parameter1,asc"
"parameter2,desc"
```

they are serialized correctly (as a list of strings with 2 elements), but if I add only one string

```
"parameter1,asc"
```

it will get serialized incorrectly as a list of strings with 2 elements (`parameter1` and `asc`).
I do not understand why the string is exploded! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the query parameter has no `style` defined, so it defaults to [`style: form`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/#query). Non-exploded form style treats the comma `,` as a separator of array items. This results in ambiguity because the values of your array items also use commas as an inner separator.

Possible solutions involve changing your backend code and/or the OpenAPI parameter definition.

- Adjust the backend code so that it splits the received `sort` string on every second comma rather than every comma.
- Or, use another [serialization method](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/#query) for the `sort` array, for example:

  - `explode: true` to send the exploded array:

    ```
    ?sort=parameter1,asc&sort=parameter2,desc
    ```
  - `style: pipeDelimited` + `explode: false` to separate array items using `|` instead of commas:

    ```
    ?sort=parameter1,asc|parameter2,desc
    ```
- Or, change `sort` to be an object/map instead of an array:

  ```json
  {
    "name": "sort",
    "in": "query",
    "description": "Sorting criteria. Example: productCode,desc",
    "required": false,
    "explode": false,
    "schema": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": ["asc", "desc"]
      }
    }
  }
  ```

  In this case, your current query string format

  ```
  ?sort=parameter1,asc,parameter2,desc
  ```

  unambiguously corresponds to:

  ```json
  {
    "parameter1": "asc",
    "parameter2": "desc"
  }
  ```

Comment: "Or, change sort to be an object/map instead of an array:" is a bad advice as it is important to save the order of values for `sort` parameter